# Navigating out of folder to a specific page.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASPX within a Folder within a Folder.

```
Administration > Users > Add.aspx
```

I want to navigate out of these 2 folders, and go to the Default.aspx page.

I'm using this : `Navigation.NavigateTo("../default.aspx", true);`

But this only gets me out of `Users` Folder.

How can I navigate out of the `Administration` Folder?

[SOLVED] **Beejee** answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use multiple "../" for each folder you want to skip.
So in your case it would be:

```
Navigation.NavigateTo("../../default.aspx", true);
```

But if you are talking about navigating to another page from inside the code you could use:

```
Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
```

The "~" will go to the root of your site.
So if your default page is in the root of your site it is better to use "~" than using the "../"

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. Will Mark as Accepted Answer, just need to wait for the countdown. Cheers:)

Comment: K also check my update to my answer.
If you want to redirect from the code behind it is better to use the second option

Comment: Yes, I saw it. It is in the root of my site. So thank you a lot ;)